# Java 8 stream transform a set of many fields in a small set with distinct values

Tags: dictionary, java-stream, distinct

I have 2 classes `Istaff` & `IstaffZone`

```java
public class Istaff   {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String location;
  private String community;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String login;
  private String locationID;
  [...]
}

public class IstaffZone {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String login;
  private String locationID;
  [...]
}
```

And a Set of `Istaff` that I want to transform to a Set of **distinct** `IstaffZone` and get only the distinct values.

I was trying to do something like ... but the result value is not distinct

```java
Set<IstaffZone> lStaffZones = new HashSet<IstaffZone>();
lStaffZones = listStaffT.stream().map(p ->  
              new IstaffZone( p.getLogin(),p.getLocationID()) )
              .distinct()
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

or

```java
List<IstaffZone> lStaffZones = new ArrayList<IstaffZone>();
lStaffZones = listStaffT.stream().map(p ->  
              new IstaffZone( p.getLogin(),p.getLocationID()) )
              .distinct()
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you implement `equals` and `hashCode` properly?

Comment: @Polygnome No. How do you implement hashCode properly? And is better Set or List?

Comment: `List` substitutes a dynamically sized indexed array allowing duplicites. `Set` keeps only unique elements and its `HashSet` implementation requires correct `hashCode` and `equals` implementation. This is a good article to start: https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to do distinct on a case-by-case basis or maybe you just don't feel like implementing a hashcode one day, you can also use the following. With this method, you can pick a single field/many fields to use as the key/hashCode on a case-by-case basis and also get the benefit of choosing which object you want on a distinct collision.

```java
List<IstaffZone> lStaffZones = new ArrayList(listStaffT.stream()
             .map(p -> new IstaffZone( p.getLogin(),p.getLocationID()) )
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       (iStaffZone) -> {
                            // return a key/hashcode that will be unique
                            // if it's just a single field, just return the field
                            return iStaffZone.getLogin + iStaffZone.getLocationID();
                       },
                       i -> i, //or Function.identity()
                       (iStaffZone1, iStaffZone2) -> x == null ? y : x)) 
                       // if iStaffZone1 and iStaffZone2 or the same, pick which gets saved
             .values());
// Collectors.toMap(a -> return key, b -> return value, (a,b) -> return element to save if same)
```